# Is it possible to save checkBox state while switching layout or class? And if its possible how?

Tags: java, layout, checkbox, android-studio

When you remember a good tutorial for checkBoxes please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the State using:

```
boolean selected = checkBox.isChecked();
```

Then you can add the `OnLayoutChangeListener` on your View Object.
Example Usage:

```
View.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener(){
   public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom){
       boolean selected = ((CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.yourCheckBoxID)).isChecked();
       //saveTheStateHere
   }
});
```